# Xcode not recognizing file

Tags: c, xcode

I added two files (takeoff.h, takeoff.c) to my Xcode project including pasting some code from another project.  Now after a successful compile, Xcode doesn't seem to recognize the new files. A call from main.c is just ignored even though everything compiles fine.  What's going on and how do I fix it?

```
 // main.c
 int main()
 {
     void test(void); // located in takeoff.c JUST IGNORED
 }

 //takeoff.c
 void test(void)
 {
     print("Printed from takeoff.c");  // no printing nor do breakpoints stop her
 {
```

Comment: Dumb mistake on my part.  The closing brace in my above comment was just a typo but I had the prototype in main, and not the actual call.  Frustrating being a novice at.  You guys are a tremendous help. Thanks.

Comment: For future reference always try to copy and paste actual code rather than re-typing, otherwise people may end up trying to fix the wrong problem due to typos etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a valid function call, just a function declaration.

```
 void test(void); // function declaration
```

Change it to `test();`

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
 // main.c

 void test(void); // <--- NB: function *prototype*

 int main()
 {
    test();  // <--- NB: function *call*
 }
```

and:

```
 // takeoff.c

 #include <stdio.h> // <--- NB: missing #include for printf

 void test(void)
 {
     printf("Printed from takeoff.c\n"); // <--- NB: *printf*, not *print*
 } // <--- NB: fixed closing brace
```

(Corrections are marked with `<---`)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .c is added to the target.  In xcode 4, it's `ALT-CMD-1`.  On the right in "Target Memberships" make sure your active target is checked.  Otherwise, everything will look like it's compiling, but it won't actually be running anything.